# Django and jQuery Coundown for Synced counting down 

Tags: django, time, countdown

I'm using the [jQuery Coundown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) with Django to generate accurate and synced data for every view.

For syncing time that is displayed on all browsers, I use [serverSync function of the plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html#zones) to pass the data (very similar to the example) like this:

```
function serverTime() { 
    var time;
    $.ajax({url: '/ajax/get-server-time/', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }});
    return time;
}
```

And my countdown init selector function is as such (I add unixtime to data of the element for the endDatetime via Django):

```
function initAllTimers(selected){
    $(selected).each(function(){
        endDatetime = new Date($(this).attr("data-unixtime") * 1000);
        $(this).countdown({until: endDatetime, serverSync: serverTime});
    });
}
```

Django template generates each field to be filled with the coundown as such:

```
<span class="timeLeft" data-unixtime="1334898000"></span>
```

And I apply timecounting to these field like like this:

```
initAllTimers('.timeLeft');
```

And finally Django view method or generating timestamp for this plugin to retrieve (via my serverTime() method):

```
#points to /ajax/get-server-time/
def get_server_time(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    response = HttpResponse( now.isoformat())
    response['Expires'] = 'Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT'
    response['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate'
    return response
```

It renders correctly but it's not synced across different computers, my Mac shows a different timeleft to my windows computer.

I suspect I make a mistake at this part:

Is the php example from countdown's example `$now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n";` same to my python function `datetime.now().isoformat()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.now().isoformat()` is not identical to `$now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")`

PHP's formatting escapes are explained here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can use `strftime()` to properly format your timestamp in Python; the docs are available here http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

`.strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %z")` should be near identical to the PHP `format()` call; if you do not get a suitable offset from `%z`, you can manually add `+0000` yourself to the Python string.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance here but I'm struggling, how can I make an equivalent to the php one ?

Comment: .strftime("%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %z") should be near identical.

Comment: Thank you cfedermann, the said strftime syns for time for my local computers however once I check from a remote computer from a different timezone, it is 2 hours behind, how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: In addition, I think that's the reason of the timezone because when I check the generated timestamp, it doesn't have a timezone: Apr 14, 2012 10:32:51